# findBy with manyToMany assosiation

Tags: doctrine-orm

Entity TestCase has 3 manyToMany assosiations "groups", "contexts" and "versions".

I'm trying to find entities by calling a method:

```
$current_condition = array('groups' => $case_groups ,'contexts' => $case_contexts , 'versions' => $case_versions );

$api->findBy(TestCase::class, $current_condition );
```

Got an error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "test_cases_group"
LINE 1: ...reated AS time_created_4 FROM test_cases t0 WHERE test_cases...
```

Doctrine's SQL:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.description AS description_3, t0.time_created AS time_created_4
FROM test_cases t0
WHERE test_cases_group.group_id IN (?) AND test_cases_contexts.context_id IN (?) AND test_cases_versions.version_id IN (?)
```

It seems like doctrine doesn't do JOINS in its sql query

Can I do such condition in findBy? Should I use query builder instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a query by yourself(using query builder) for this kind of criteria.
Doctrine doesn't support complex criteria like this in findBy() method.

Comment: Yes, I should extend base repository and write my own complex queries. Thank you.